# Browser Service don't work on android device

Tags: javafx, gluon

I have uses the Browser Service for Gluon charm down. But It not work. Someone can help me please? I don't have any Error . That is my Build.gradle

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.1'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {

    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0'
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'
    androidCompile 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'
    androidRuntime 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.15.1'
    compile group: 'org.sqldroid', name: 'sqldroid', version: '1.0.3'   
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-desktop', version: '0.0.2'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-common', version: '0.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-android', version: '0.0.1'
    compileNoRetrolambda 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.2'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-browser', version: '3.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-barcode-scan-android', version: '3.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-battery', version: '3.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-dialer-android', version: '3.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-pictures', version: '3.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-position', version: '3.2.0'










}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.1.0'
        plugins 'cache','display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {

        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.ensemble'




    }

    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonapplication.**.*',
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*',
                'ensemble.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

and i have implemented the Service like so

```
public void browser() {
        Services.get(BrowserService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
            try {
                service.launchExternalBrowser("www.google.com");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

After i add it in a Button to the Scene Builder

The Position  and Barcode-Scan Plugin do not works also fine
 Here is how i have implemented it.

```
public void position() {
        Services.get(PositionService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
            Position position = service.getPosition();
            System.out.printf("Current position: %.5f, %.5f", position.getLatitude(), position.getLongitude());
            LS4.setText(position.getLatitude() + " /" + position.getLongitude() + "");
        });

    } 


public void barCode() {
        Services.get(BarcodeScanService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
            BarcodeScanService barcodeScanService = (BarcodeScanService) new BarcodeScanServiceFactory();
            Optional<String> barcode = barcodeScanService.scan();
            barcode.ifPresent(barcodeValue -> LS4.setText(barcodeValue));

        });
    }
```

and that is my androidmanifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.gluonapplication" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
        <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
        <application android:label="MultiViewProjectFXML" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
                <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:labe
```

l="MultiViewProjectFXML" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">

Comment: Post your build.gradle file so we can see the Down config, and a code snippet of how you use the plugin.

Comment: @JoséPereda I Update the Post and Update the Git Repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build contains wrong dependencies, and the plugins should be managed by the `downConfig` configuration.

It will take care of adding the proper plugins and for the proper platform.

Modify your dependencies and plugins like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.0'
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'
    androidCompile 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'
    androidRuntime 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    desktopCompile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.15.1'
    desktopCompile group: 'org.sqldroid', name: 'sqldroid', version: '1.0.3'   
    compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.3'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.2.0'
        plugins 'barcode-scan', 'battery', 'browser', 'cache', 'dialer', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'picture', 'position', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
}
```

As for the Browser service, you'll need to include `http://`.

Comment: Thanks. I update the Projekt. It works now. Do you know how to use the Android Emulator with Gluon Plugin and Gradle to test the App in a Android Emulator?

Comment: There is no easy way to use an emulator with the jfxmobile plugin. Check this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/issues/65/emulator)

Comment: I have Test the Position and Barcode-Scan it not works fine. When i click the Button for Position and barcode-scan the app go close. I have update the Post

Comment: Make sure you add the required permissions to the AndroidManifest. See the [doc](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/latest/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/PositionService.html) for them

Comment: I have update the Post. I have already the required Permissions to the AndroidManifest

Comment: If there is a crash, there is an exception: go to your android sdk folder, access platform-tools and run `adb logcat -v threadtime` from command line with your mobile connected. Run the app and try to find the exception in the console.

Comment: in have this error "Attempt to invoke double com.gluon.charm.down.plugins.Position.getLatitude() on a null Objekt referemce

Comment: You should create a new question with that (post relevant code and stacktrace). It is impossible to solve it within these comments.

Comment: Ok i make it tomorrow. I don't have internet at home